# Dynamically calling functions

Tags: function, flutter, dart, dynamic

Is there a method to call a function dynamically in Dart?

For example, in C/C++ I can use function pointers. In PHP/Javascript I can use the function name.

What I would like to achieve is placing functions in a list and iterate over the list of function to call them all on the same piece of data. How can I best accomplish this in dart?

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use closures and function tear-offs to achieve this. Here's an example:

```dart
foo(String x) => print('Foo: $x');
bar(String x) => print('Bar: $x');

main() {
  final functions = [foo, bar, (String x) => print('Closure: $x')];
  for (final f in functions) {
    f('data');
  }
}
```

Which will output:

```
Foo: data
Bar: data
Closure: data
```

Comment: Thank you. I actually found that my code worked if instead of making the list of function names strings, I typed it as Function. I.e.: List<Function> functionList = [func1, func2, func3, ...]; I can then use an index into the list to execute the desired function. My purpose for doing this is that I need to call the functions in a specific order and apply them to the same piece of data. However, sometimes I will need to skip ahead a few methods depending on the result of a particular function I may need to skip the next function or two.